# Rails Daemon stays in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon

I have a Rails application with a daemon that checks a mailbox for any new emails. I am using the [Fetcher](http://github.com/look/fetcher/tree/master) plugin for this task. The daemon file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment.rb'

class MailFetcherDaemon < Daemon::Base

  @config = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/mail.yml")
  @config = @config['production'].to_options

  @sleep_time = @config.delete(:sleep_time) || 20
  def self.start
    puts "Starting MailFetcherDaemon"
    # Add your own receiver object below
    @fetcher = Fetcher.create({:receiver => MailProcessor}.merge(@config))
  ...
```

So I have it grab the new emails, parse them and create a resource from the parsed data. But when it tries to save the resource an exception is thrown. This is because the script  is automatically assigned the development environment. So it is using my development database configuration instead of the production environment (which is the config that I want).

I have tried starting the script with:

```
 rails-root$ RAILS_ENV=production; script/mail_fetcher start
```

but to no avail. It seems like when I load the environment.rb file it just defaults to the development environment and loads development.rb and the development database configuration from database.yml.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working in my app, the only difference I see is no semi-colon

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/mail_fetcher start
```

Answer (score 1):

So when you say

```
RAILS_ENV=production; script/mail_fetcher start
```

do you mean

```
#!/bin/bash
export RAILS_ENV=production
cd /path/to/rails_root
./script/mail_fetcher start
```

Comment: Yeah that's the command I was doing but I had it in shorthand. I updated the question to indicate where I was running the command from.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding this to your script:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "production"
```

Alternatively, it might work to add it to the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/rails_root
./script/mail_fetcher start RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: I tried that but I need the environment to be set to 'production' as the environment.rb file is loaded this way it will load the production configuration (the settings for the database, mailier, logger, etc)